# Executing some code when the .net framework version is older than the program's version

Tags: .net

Is there anyway to execute some code when the user launches the program and his .Net framework version is older than the program's .net version.

For example run the .net framework setup instead of getting the error that says that your .net version is...
Thanks,

Comment: No, because in order for the program to run on the target framework (to display your desired message) the target framework has to be installed.  It's like a catch 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but I doubt you will like the answer. If you want this to happen the thing that is "executing some code" can't be written in .NET.

Installers are usually written in native (non .NET) code, those can check for things like .NET being installed and act on it (like running the .NET installer). There are many tools out there to write installers without needing to know a native language like C++ or C. [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is a popular one, it can create an installer for you and all you need to do is set up some XML configuration files.

The other option, if you know a native language, is to write a "launcher" which checks for .NET, runs whatever code you want, then launches your .NET app. This is a much steeper learning curve if you don't already know a language but if you do know a language it might be the easier task.